# Double Content add query front css content

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

For some reason whenever I add the word menu next to me hamburger icon it spits out two copies of it. I'm told this is due to a query string. I've added code to my functions.php file that should have stopped this, but still its not working.

[image: here is what it looks like]
This is what my css class looks like:

```
<style>
.slide-out-widget-area-toggle a span:after {
    content: "MENU";
    font-size: 18px !important;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    position: relative;
    left: -81px !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear;
    top: 3px !important;
    opacity: 1;
}
</style>
```

You can find the live example here. The https password is guest guest. http://bca2017.bluecircleadvisors.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 elements in your DOM, where your CSS selector applies to:

```
#top > div > div > div.col.span_9.col_last > nav > ul.buttons > li.slide-out-widget-area-toggle > div > a > span::after
```

and

```
#ajax-content-wrap > div > div > a > span::after
```

Eliminate one of those, and you will have only one "MENU" label.